# Powershell , Cannot save as that name. Document was opened as read-only

Tags: excel, powershell

How to avoid remove read-only , I need to normal excel without read-only.
I have below code:

```
$excelfile="C:\Users\Administrator\Pictures\unprotect_org - Copy\unprotect - Copy (2).xlsx"
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $false
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excelfile,$true,123)
$wb.SaveAs($excelfile,[Type]::Missing,$password)
$excel.Quit()
```

I got below error:

```
Cannot save as that name. Document was opened as read-only.
At line:1 char:1
+ $wb.SaveAs($excelfile,[Type]::Missing,$password)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

[image]

2nd things , why microsoft execel open in task manager, How can I close this exe.
[image]

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: The third parameter of `Open` is read-only, and PowerShell converts `123` to `$true`, so change `$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excelfile,$true,123)` to `$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excelfile,$true,$false)`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen , How can I get property of workbooks.open? Is there any site for reference.

Comment: It maps to this VBA interface, you can see the 3rd param is `ReadOnly`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things you'll want to change - opening in read-write mode, and ensuring `Quit()` is called regardless of terminating errors.

To avoid opening the workbook in read-only mode, change the value of the 3rd parameter argument passed to [`Open()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open):

```
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excelfile,$true,$false)
#                                              ^ 
#                                     This is the ReadOnly parameter
```

To ensure `Quit()` is always called, use a `try`/`finally` statement:

```
$excelfile="C:\Users\Administrator\Pictures\unprotect_org - Copy\unprotect - Copy (2).xlsx"
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
try {
  $excel.Visible = $false
  $excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
  $wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excelfile,$true,123)
  $wb.SaveAs($excelfile,[Type]::Missing,$password)
}
finally {
  $excel.Quit()
}
```

If PowerShell reaches the first statement inside the `try` block, it guarantees that the `finally` block will execute before returning control from the block - even if the call to `SaveAs()` (or any other invocation) throws a terminating exception

Comment: I have same issue related to unprotect excel.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71278064/powershell-excelxlsx-how-unprotect-excel-sheet-and-excel-workbooks-with-know-p