# Powershell excel(xlsx) how unprotect excel sheet and excel workbooks with know password

Tags: excel, powershell

I have below code:

```
$excelfile="C:\Users\Administrator\Pictures\unprotect_org - Copy (2)\unprotect - Copy (2).xlsx"
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $false
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excelfile,$false,123)
$wb.Unprotect(123);
$wb.Settings.Password = "";
$wb.Save($excelfile);
$excel.Quit()
```

I have problem with, PS script is opening ui excel application instead of remove password as without open excel.
[image]

Getting below error:

```
Unable to get the Open property of the Workbooks class
At line:1 char:1
+ $wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excelfile,$false,123)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

Please help to unprotect excel sheets and workbook using powershell.

Comment: as in your previous question, `123` is incorrect

Comment: @Theo , $password=123. I hope you understand the exact issue which I have faced.

Comment: I meant here: `$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excelfile,$false,123)`. That third parameter is for opening as Read-ONly. Because it is a [boolean] value (either $true or $false), **any number** unequal to 0 is considered $true.

Comment: @Theo, I wanna unprotect excel using this above command but it seems not working even I tried as per your suggestions $wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excelfile,$false,$false,123)  , but getting error like 
Unable to get the Open property of the Workbooks class

Comment: There, you did it again... Use `$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excelfile,$false,$false)` to prevent the error you're now seeing. Your code will probably generate the next error then, but at least with that you have overcome the first hurdle. Please do some reading on the parameters you can give on the [Workbooks.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open) method.

Comment: To open an Excel workbook with a password, you need to specify that password as the **fith** parameter: `$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excelfile, $false, $false, [Type]::Missing, $password)` (where `$password` contains the string "123" in this case)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, here you go:

To open an Excel workbook with a password, you need to specify that password as the **fith** parameter on the `Workbooks.Open()`  method:

```
$password = '123'
$excelfile = "C:\Users\Administrator\Pictures\unprotect_org - Copy (2)\unprotect - Copy (2).xlsx"
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $false
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excelfile, $false, $false, [Type]::Missing, $password)
# remove the protection from this workbook
$wb.Unprotect($password)
# should not be needed, but does no harm
$wb.Password=$null
# close the workbook and save the changes
$wb.Close($true)
$excel.Quit()
# Important: remove the used COM objects from memory
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wb)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```